# Getting the elements in a 2D vector (matrix)

Tags: scala

I am searching a vector of vectors for a specific int.

```
  def searchVectors(i: Int, vectors: Vector[Vector[Int]]) = {
    val x = vectors.indexWhere(_.indexWhere(_ == i))
    val y = vectors(x).indexOf(y)
    (x, y)
  }
```

You can see I get the y twice.  Firstly when computing x and then again when computing y.
Not good.  How do I do it so I only compute y once?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, I would name item to lookup as `x` or `z` or somehow other than `i` (i,j,k are for indexes)

Comment: also your code doesn't compile

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The one approach you can take is to just iterate all vectors:

```
def searchVectors(x: Int, vec: Vector[Vector[Int]]) =
  for {
    i <- 0 until vec.size
    j <- 0 until vec(i).size
    if vec(i)(j) == x
  } yield (i, j)
```

Vector also have `zipWithIndex` method, which adds index to each element of the collection and creates a tuple of them. So you can use it in order to archive the same thing:

```
def searchVectors(x: Int, vec: Vector[Vector[Int]]) =
  for {
    (subVec, i) <- vec.zipWithIndex
    (elem, j) <- subVec.zipWithIndex
    if elem == x
  } yield (i, j)
```

The advantage of this approach, is that instead of external (index-based) loop, you are using internal loop with `map`/`flatMap`. If you will combine it with views, then you can implement lazy search:

```
def searchVectors(x: Int, vec: Vector[Vector[Int]]) =
  for {
    (subVec, i) <- vec.view.zipWithIndex
    (elem, j) <- subVec.view.zipWithIndex
    if elem == x
  } yield (i, j)
```

Not you will still receive collection of results, but it's lazy collection. So if you will take it's head like this:

```
searchVectors(3, vector).headOption
```

It will actually perform search (only at this point) and then, when it's found, it would be returned as `Option`. No further search will be performed.

Comment: But isn't indexWhere shortcircuting whereas your approach is not? (moreover, it would return collection, not a single element)

Comment: @om-nom-nom yeah, you are right, with my solution you will receive all found elements of vector.

Comment: @om-nom-nom I updated the answer. By using views I actually implemented shortcircuting on-demand.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more functional approach to do it:

```
def searchVectors(i: Int, vectors: Vector[Vector[Int]]) = {
  val outer = vectors.toStream map (_.indexOf(i))
  outer.zipWithIndex.filter(_._1 != -1).headOption map (_.swap)
}
```

EDIT: I think I like this even better:

```
def searchVectors(i: Int, vectors: Vector[Vector[Int]]) = {
  vectors.toStream.map(_.indexOf(i)).zipWithIndex.collectFirst {
    case (y, x) if y != -1 => (x, y)
  }
}
```

Converting to a `Stream` is optional, but probably more efficient because it avoids searching the whole vector if the desired element has already been found.

Answer (score 2):

This bothered me too. You may have already thought of this, but if you are willing to violate the functional programming principle of immutable state etc. here is one possible approach:

```
val v = Vector(Vector(1,2,3), Vector(4, 5, 6))
var c: Int = -1
val r = v.indexWhere(r => {c = r.indexOf(6); c != -1})
(r, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a easy-to-understand solution

```
def searchVectors(i: Int, vectors: Vector[Vector[Int]]): (Int, Int) = {
    val row = vectors.indexWhere(_.contains(i)) // Try to get index of vector containing element
    if (row > -1) (row, vectors(row).indexOf(i)) // (row, col)
    else (-1, -1)
}
```